# Send Form with email attached in PHP

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have an html form.I want to send it to clients.

What are the best ways to send to client via email so that client can download this form

I tried to cread pdf and send that pdf document BUT I can not create proper pdf from my html.

So is there any other way to do with out pdf?

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$sr =  $filename . '.pdf';
$pdf->Output('tmp_email/'.$sr, 'F');
```

Note:My email function is working good...

My question is what type of document should i created without pdf?
Can i send html as attached?how?

Answer (score 0):

Swiftmailer is a good option for creating HTML emails:
http://swiftmailer.org/

When generating PDFs from HTML, you might want to take a look at domPDF: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

It supports images, external stylesheets and loads of other things:
http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php

Comment: i can send html emails,question is how to convert my html to SOMETHING which client can download and use for himself

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been playing with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). It's really simple to use and the source code for it is easy to understand. There is also a good manual on their website with examples and function references.

You would have to recreate your HTML page layout using FPDF though (I didn't find it to much of a problem).

> FPDF has other advantages: high level functions. Here is a list of its
>   main features:
>
> - Choice of measure unit, page format and margins
> - Page header and footer management
> - Automatic page break
> - Automatic line break and text justification
> - Image support (JPEG, PNG and GIF)
> - Colors
> - Links
> - TrueType, Type1 and encoding support
> - Page compression

Answer (score 0):

Did you try tcpdf ? I have used that before creating forms and found no issues. 
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.pdf